# Detecting blast cap removal from C4

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

In many Television shows (such as NCIS (all of them), Criminal Minds, MacGyver, etc.) there is a bomb consisting of electronics and C4 explosive.

Mythbusters have determined that a blasting cap is required to detonate the C4 explosive; no other techniques work (such as applying heat or compression).

The people who disarm the bomb always mess with the electronics.  They don't mess with the C4 blasting cap (like removing it from the C4 or cutting the cords to the blasting cap).

Questions:
1) Can electronics detect the removal of the blasting cap from C4?

2) Is resistance futile (of the C4) for detecting that the blasting cap is inside C4 explosive?

I'm having an issue with these bomb sleuths as to why they don't pull the blasting caps out from the C4 before disarming the electronics (if necessary).

(I'm a software engineer with a fundamental understanding of electronics.)

Comment: a blasting cap is like a thermal heater that ignites some compact powder which in turn ignites the C4.  SHorting out the blasting cap wires makes it safe.

Comment: Voting to close as this question is going to attract all sorts of uninformed opinion. For a fictional view of how gnarly this problem can be watch Juggernaut (1974).

Comment: How do you know that the people that disarm the bomb always mess with the electronics?  Don't believe everything you see on TV -- that's just what makes the best TV.

Comment: I've rarely seen the bomb experts remove the blasting cap.  Usually, they are discussing which wire to cut.  We won't get started on the unnecessary timer display.

Comment: I would prefer not having people close this.  I could ask another question about detecting the removal of an electromagnet nail from clay.  IMHO, same circumstances, but a lot safer. :-)

Comment: How many times have you seen "bomb experts" disarming a bomb.  I've been around a while, and I've seen this exactly zero times.

Comment: While I know there are many resources for creating weapons and bombs online, I have hesitation contributing to any of them. Particularly when a question sounds like its wondering how to booby-trap or fool-proof a bomb.

Answer (score 3):

If a real expert suspects that an explosive device has anti handling enhancements they will not touch it. This includes cutting wires, shorting wires or pulling detonators/det cord primers out of charges.

You do not need electronics to detect detonator removal there is a device used in booby trapping called a comb switch this device can sense pull/push pressure applied or pressure removed, it contains its own detonator. It could be hidden within the charge and simple piece of nylon line would cause detonation if a detonator was pulled out.

Although interesting this has nothing to do with EE.

The usual approach to this type of device is to use an explosive disrupter which produces a hyper velocity water slug which scatters the device fast enough to prevent most of the main charge detonating.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you could design a circuit to be sensitive to unskilled tampering and detonate if not disarmed properly.

The blast cap could be designed to detonate when a clock signal is *removed*, for example. As long as the clock pulses keep coming in, the bomb does nothing, but if the timer expires, or the blast cap is forcibly removed, then those clock pulses are interrupted, and boom.

In this example, you'd need to find some careful method of disabling the thing that is listening for the clock pulses, hence, the careful electronics work/find the right wire to cut.

Comment: The clock signal can handle the cutting of one of the blasting cap wires, but how does the electronics detect the removal of a blasting cap from the C4?  Consider a big nail with wires attached, inserted into clay, as an example.

Comment: The ultimate trap... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey%27s_Resort_Hotel_bombing